# Convergence of series with integral test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Given that the following series is convergent, determine the values of p.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n(\log(n))^p}$$

So far what I have done is using the integral test, in order to use integral test, I set p $\in(0, \infty)$ to make f(x) decreasing.

Therefore I got:

$$\int_{2}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\dfrac{1}{(p-1)[\log(2)]^{1-p}}$$ which exist for $p\neq1$.

So my answer is $p\in(1,\infty)$, perhaps my question is stupid (sorry about that), but am I on the right track, didn't I make any mistakes?

thanks

Comment: You're right. A series  $\sum\limits_{n\ge2}\dfrac1{ n^a\log^bn}$ is known as a *Bertrand's  series*, and it is convergent if $a>1$  or $a=1, \enspace b>1$.

Comment: I got it, thanks you so much

Comment: somehow I have no idea about why $\int log(x) dx = \int ln(x) dx$ @Bernard

Comment: I m' not sure I see what you mean. Is it: why $\log =\ln$?

Comment: thats exactly my question as well, since the answer seems missing a constant $ln(10)$ for changing base ?

Comment: I think they use the old name of the function (still is use for the logarithm of a complex number) – which, by the way, was **Log**.

Comment: aw  i see, thanks :)

Comment: @ArnaudD. This post is years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral to be compared with is
$$\int_2^{\infty}\dfrac{dx}{x\ln^p(x)} = \int_{\ln2}^{\infty} \dfrac{dt}{t^p} = \left. \dfrac{t^{1-p}}{1-p}\right \vert_{\ln2}^{\infty} = - \dfrac{(\ln2)^{1-p}}{1-p} + \lim_{t\to \infty} \dfrac{t^{1-p}}{1-p}$$
The limit exists only for $p>1$ and doesn't exist for $p \leq 1$. Hence, the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n\ln^p(n)}$$ converges for $p>1$ and diverges for $p \leq 1$.

Comment: How did you go from the first to second step? I can't see it.

Comment: @user57404 Make the substitution $t=\ln(x)$ and see what happens.

Comment: Ah okay, I was definitely looking too hard. Thought it'd be a complicated sub.  Wow.

Comment: somehow I have no idea about why $\int log(x) dx = \int ln(x) dx$

Comment: @Alan For mathematician, $\log$ means $\ln$. For non-mathematician, typically $\log$ denotes $\log_{10}$.